# Need help cropping a large text file to multiple small text files with a header

Tags: python, csv, text

I need to crop a large text file with over 10000 lines of numbers in addition to a header with the format (number_of_lines, number_difference, "Sam")

Number_difference is the difference between the first and last number.

For example, if the file looks like this:

```
10
12
13.5
17
20
```

Then, the header should be:
    5 10 Sam

The problem is the flags do not work for not writing a header more than once and the big file's header carries over to the 1st small file.

The headers will never be the same for each file.

How do I add a changing header to each file?

```
def TextCropper():


lines_per_file = 1000
smallfile = None
with open(inputFileName) as bigfile:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(bigfile):
            if lineno % lines_per_file == 0:
                if smallfile:
                    smallfile.close()
                    small_filename = 'small_file_{}.txt'.format(lineno + lines_per_file)
                    smallfile = open(small_filename, "w")
                    if (flags[counter] == False):
                        smallfile.write(lines_per_file)
                        flags[counter] = True
                    smallfile.write(line)
            elif smallfile:
                smallfile.close()
```

TextCropper()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading and writing the lines one at a time, which is inefficient. By doing that, you also don't know what the last line will be, so you can't write your header in advance.

Just read up to N lines, if available. `islice()` will do exactly that for you. If the list comes back empty, there were no lines left to read, otherwise you can proceed to write the current chunk into a file.

Since each line is read as a number with a trailing newline ('\n'), strip that, convert the first and last numbers into floats and calculate the difference. Writing the actual numbers to the file is straightforward by joining the elements of the list.

To make the function reusuable, include the variables that are likely to change as arguments. That way you can name any big file, any output small file and any number of lines you want without changing hardcoded values.

```
from itertools import islice

def number_difference(iterable):
    return float(iterable[-1].strip('\n')) - float(iterable[0].strip('\n'))

def file_crop(big_fname, chunk_fname, no_lines):
    with open(big_fname, 'r') as big_file:
        ifile = 0
        while True:
            data = list(islice(big_file, no_lines))
            if not data:
                break
            with open('{}_{}.txt'.format(chunk_fname, ifile), 'w') as small_file:
                small_file.write('{} {} Sam\n'.format(len(data), number_difference(data)))
                small_file.write(''.join(data))
            ifile += 1
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how you're using the program, but it should work for a file like you had described in the question, i.e., lines of text comprised only of a single number each. If you put `'45'` as input in `float()`, it will come out as `45.0`. But if you put `45fdr`, it will fail. Given the error you got, it seems you tried to use the program for a file with a header created by the same program.

Comment: There is a header in the original file. What is a smart way to delete the header that isn't manually? Some of the numbers are 45.12352 and not all are integers

Comment: If you always guarantee to have a header in the original file that you want to ignore, then as soon as you open the file, just do `big_file.readline()`, right before `ifile = 0`. That will discard the first line, since you don't save it to any variable and will move the cursor ready to start reading from the second line.

Comment: Thanks! I will review your code and learn how to make more generic programs.

Comment: How would I modify the code so that I subtract the first number as an integer from the rest of the number? Say the first position is 12345.678 and the next position is 12346.978. I would change the first position to int(round(float(iterable[0].strip('\n')))) and subtract it from both positions. The new lines would be 0.6780 and 1.9780 respectively. I want to use islice without using another tedious for loop.

Comment: Are we talking about lines of numbers you read from the big file, such as 10.1, 12, 13.5, etc? And before saving them to a small file you want to convert them to 0.1, 2, 3.5?

Comment: Also note that this only happens **within each new file** and NOT the big file. So one window's number to be subtracted will differ from the next. It might be best to use the window size to do this for all by subtracting the first number in one set of 1000 for only that 1000 set and then moving onto the next one.

Comment: You can't avoid a loop, since you have to apply that operation on each element. Since `data` is the list of numbers for a specific chunk, you can modify them easily. `offset = int(float(data[0].strip('\n')))` and then `map(lambda x: str(float(x.strip('\n')) - offset) + '\n', data)`. `map()` is a loop under the hood, which will apply a specific function to each element in your list.

Comment: Any types for fixing screwy decimal places to only 4 digits?  `small_file.write(''.join(map(lambda x: str(float(x.strip('\n')) - offset) + '\n', data)))` produces results like 0.0799999999999, 0.683999999999
, and 0.986000000001 but `small_file.write(''.join(map(lambda x: str(float("{0:.4f}".format(x.strip('\n'))) - offset) + '\n', data)))` throws an error

Comment: The conversion should happen after `if not data`, since you rely on `data[0]` existing. The numbers seems to be the result of [floating point limitations](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). You can use `round(float(...), 4)` to restrict a number to 4 digits.

Comment: How would I add a step_size to this program? `data = list(islice(big_file, no_lines, None, step_size))` produces no windows at all when I implement it

Comment: I don't understand what `step_size` is. The original question and my answer to it made no reference to windows. Just a big file of numbers which is split in a bunch of smaller files, all with at most `no_lines` number of lines.

Comment: I need to add a sliding window algorithm to this text file now instead of just the regular code that exists right now. The 'no_lines' will become the 'window_size' and the step_size

Comment: That sounds like you should ask a new question since it creates new complications. The question (and answers) here should only be concerned with what you posed it to be initially.